# Why was this suggested edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

How does [this suggested edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/175861) “change too much in the original post”? In what way would “the original meaning or intent of the post” be lost?

The question as it stands has a few problems:

1. It has a title beginning with [an unnecessary prefix](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/151579/unnecessary-question-labelling).
2. It relies on a comment, when we are constantly warned that comments are “second-class citizens” and may be removed at any time.
3. It has a title which does not reflect the actual question asked: The question in the title is answered (by the comment). The *actual* question is about problems *similar to* the one in the title.

My suggested edit fixed all these problems.

1. The text of the comment was incorporated into the question, using [spoiler markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396). This preserves the original author’s intent of making that content available, but not immediately obvious.
2. The title was rewritten to reflect the actual question asked. The unnecessary prefix was removed as part of this process.

I do not see how this edit could be seen as too radical.

Comment: BTW, the word is straightedge (one word) as it was originally written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't one of the reviewers (as you can tell), but I would guess that they did not notice that your inserted text was actually from a comment.  The "Suggested Edits Review" screen only shows the post as is together with the suggested edit side-by-side (with differences highlighted).  While you mentioned in your description that these additions came from a comment, reviewers have to do extra work to check that this is the case.  I wouldn't be surprised that the rejecting reviewers saw the sheer size of the addition and rejected on that basis alone.

Comment: Well, the problems still exist. I'll leave that (and the other [unnecessarily prefixed questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/151579/unnecessary-question-labelling)) to you, so.

Comment: Should reviewers who are too lazy to read be barred from reviewing?